# Change number to letter for \paragraph

Tags: sectioning, numbering, paragraphs

I would like to use `\paragraph{}` as a subsubsubsection. It's working fine but I want to change the number to a letter.

For example instead of having 1.1.1.1 I would like to have 1.1.1.a.

How can I do that ?

Thx !

Comment: It's working ! However, I tried with `\renewcommand*{\theparagraph}{\thesubsubsection.\alph{\theparagraph}}` like it's done with the sections, subsections etc, but the keyword is not recognized. Do you know why ?

Comment: Yeah I know but why the keyword has not the same shape as the ones for section ? For a section we use `\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\alph{\thesection}}` right ? So why it's not the same for the paragraph ?

Comment: No, for a section you do `\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\alph{section}}`. The argument of `\alph` is a counter, and `\alph{XXX}` expands internally to a counter named `\c@XXX`.

Comment: Okay my bad :p Thx ! You can post an answer if you want so I can mark the topic as answered